# calculate the limit of a numerical sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, sequence-of-function

$(Sn)= \sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+i}}$

I need to proove that the limit of this sequence equals $2$  but i'm stuck here. i tried give the sequence upper and lower bounds to use " gendarme" but it doesn't seem to work. any help would be appreciated

Comment: yes of course! i forgot to add it

Answer (score 2):

Since each term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+i}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}} = \frac{1}{n+1}$ and we have $2n$ terms, we have a lower bound of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{n+1} = 2$.

We also have for each term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+i}} \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Again, we have $2n$ terms and so we get an upper bound of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{n} = 2$.

Thus by the Squeeze Theorem (or "gendarme") the limit must equal 2.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if
$S_n
=\sum_{i=1}^{an+b} \dfrac1{\sqrt{n^2+i}}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
S_n
&=\sum_{i=1}^{an+b} \dfrac1{\sqrt{n^2+i}}\\
&\lt\sum_{i=1}^{an+b} \dfrac1{\sqrt{n^2}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{an+b} \dfrac1{n}\\
&=\dfrac{an+b}{n}\\
&=a+\dfrac{b}{n}\\
&\to a\\
\text{and}\\
S_n
&=\sum_{i=1}^{an+b} \dfrac1{\sqrt{n^2+i}}\\
&\gt\sum_{i=1}^{an+b} \dfrac1{\sqrt{n^2+an+b}}\\
&\gt\sum_{i=1}^{an+b} \dfrac1{n\sqrt{1+a/n+b/n^2}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{an+b} \dfrac1{n(1+a/(2n)+b/(2n^2))}
\qquad\text{since } \sqrt{1+x} < 1+x/2\\
&=\dfrac{an+b}{n+a/2+b/(2n)}\\
&=\dfrac{a+b/n}{1+a/2n)+b/(2n^2)}\\
&\gt(a+b/n)(1-a/(2n)-b/(2n^2))
\qquad\text{since }1/(1+x) > 1-x\\
&=a+(b-a/2)/n-ab/n^2-b^2/(2n^3)\\
&\to a\\
\end{array}
$

so
$S_n \to a$.

Answer (score 0):

Each term is between
$1/\sqrt{n^2+1}$
and
$1/\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}$
or
$1/n$ and 
$1/(n+1)$.

Comment: thank you that is what i was looking for !

Comment: but how can i proove for example that the limit of the sum of $1/n+1$ is $2$

Comment: There are 2n terms, each of which is about 1/n.